# Google maps GPS navigation

Tags: google-maps

How can I set GPS navigation through Google maps in an app? I tried looking into the maps api but couldn't find anything much helpful. So let me know how i can set navigation in an app.

Answer (score 0):

What is called navigation Google named Directions
https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/directions/intro
which is available for free subscribtion as well.